# A2C is not working due to critic loss is not converging

Tags: tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

I'm trying to do my own implementation of the Advantage Actor Critic algorithm by using tensorflow. I used the code in https://github.com/BoYanSTKO/Practical_RL-coursera/blob/master/week5_policy_based/practice_a3c.ipynb as a rough template on how I should write the algorithm.

I tried it on the simple CartPole-v0 gym environment but by implementation fails badly. The critics loss just explodes and becomes way to large while the actors loss is rather low.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any help? :)

I've tried separating the actor and critic from each other by having 2 different networks. This did not help either. Have also tried fine tuning some stuff like gamma and learning rate without any success.

## !/usr/bin/python

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import gym
import random
from tensorboardX import SummaryWriter

class ActorCritic():

```
def __init__(self,state_dim,n_actions,learning_rate,gamma=0.99):

    with tf.variable_scope("ActorCritic"):

        self.states_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,(None,state_dim),name="states")
        self.action_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.int32,(None,),name="actions")
        self.n_actions = n_actions
        self.reward_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,(None,),name="rewards")

        self.next_state_values = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,(None,),name="rewards")
        self.is_done_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,(None,),name="rewards")

        net = tf.layers.dense(self.states_ph,24,activation=tf.nn.relu)

        self.logits = tf.layers.dense(net,n_actions,activation=None)
        self.state_values = tf.layers.dense(net,1,activation=None)

        self.action_probs = tf.nn.softmax(self.logits)

        self.log_prob = tf.nn.log_softmax(self.logits)

        self.entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(self.action_probs*self.log_prob,axis=-1,name="entropy")

        self.logp_actions = tf.reduce_sum(self.log_prob*tf.one_hot(self.action_ph,depth=n_actions),axis=-1)

        self.target_state_values = self.reward_ph + gamma*(1.0-self.is_done_ph)*self.next_state_values

        self.advantage = self.target_state_values - self.state_values

        self.actor_loss  = -tf.reduce_mean(self.logp_actions * tf.stop_gradient(self.advantage)) - 0.01*tf.reduce_mean(self.entropy)

        self.critic_loss = tf.reduce_mean(self.advantage**2.0)

        self.train_opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(self.actor_loss+self.critic_loss)

def train(self,states,actions,rewards,is_done,nxt_state_values_batch):

    sess = tf.get_default_session()
    return sess.run([self.critic_loss,self.actor_loss,self.train_opt],feed_dict={
        self.next_state_values:nxt_state_values_batch,
        self.states_ph:states,
        self.action_ph:actions,
        self.reward_ph:rewards,
        self.is_done_ph:is_done})

def predict_state_values(self,states):
    sess = tf.get_default_session()
    return sess.run(self.state_values,feed_dict={self.states_ph:states})

def sample_actions(self,states):
    sess = tf.get_default_session()
    action_probs = sess.run(self.action_probs,{self.states_ph:states})
    return [ np.random.choice(range(self.n_actions),p=action_prob) for action_prob in action_probs ]
```

class EnvBatch():

```
def __init__(self,env_name,n_envs):

    self.envs = [gym.make(env_name) for env in range(n_envs)]
    self.n_actions = self.envs[0].action_space.n
    self.state_dim = self.envs[0].observation_space.shape[0]

def reset(self):
    return [env.reset().tolist() for env in self.envs ]

def step(self,actions):
    states_batch, rewards_batch, is_done_batch = [], [], []

    for action, env in zip(actions,self.envs):

        s, r , d, _ = env.step(action)
        if d:
            s = env.reset()

        states_batch.append(s)
        rewards_batch.append(r)
        is_done_batch.append(d)

    return np.array(states_batch), np.array(rewards_batch), np.array(is_done_batch)
```

def evaluate_performance(env_name,agent,nr_runs=10):

```
env = gym.make(env_name)
rewards = []

for _ in range(nr_runs):

    state = env.reset()
    is_done = False

    acc_reward = 0.0

    while not is_done:

        action = agent.sample_actions([state])
        nxt_state, reward, is_done, _ = env.step(action[0])
        state = nxt_state
        acc_reward += reward

    rewards.append(acc_reward)

return np.mean(rewards)
```

tf.reset_default_graph()

env = EnvBatch("CartPole-v0",10)
agent = ActorCritic(env.state_dim,env.n_actions,learning_rate=0.001)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

state_batch = env.reset()
writer = SummaryWriter()

for i in range(100000):

```
actions = agent.sample_actions(state_batch)

nxt_state_batch, rewards_batch, is_done_batch = env.step(actions)

nxt_state_values = agent.predict_state_values(nxt_state_batch).ravel()

critic_loss, actor_loss, _ = agent.train(state_batch,actions,rewards_batch,is_done_batch,nxt_state_values)

writer.add_scalar("actor_loss",actor_loss,i)
writer.add_scalar("critic_loss",critic_loss,i)

if i%50==0:
    test_reward = evaluate_performance("CartPole-v0",agent)
    writer.add_scalar("test_reward",test_reward,i)
    if test_reward > 195:
        print "Done!"

states_batch = nxt_state_batch
```

sess.close()
writer.close()

Comment: Hey peps. Found a solution to my problem. I included a target network for the critic which is updated with the "reference" critic network every 100:th step. This seems solve the problem with the exploding critics loss.